# UICollectionView shadow doesnt show up correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

so I'm making an tabbarcontroller and in my tabbarcontroller have 2 collectionview, collectionview 1 height is about 50px and the 2nd is right below it with constraint 0 to all side and I'm trying to set the shadow for the colletionview1 without the collectionview2 the shadow show up correctly but with the collectionview2 or any UIView right below the collectionview1 they seem to cover up the shadow that I set for collectionview1

```
func setupMenuBarShadow() {
    menuBarCollectionView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    menuBarCollectionView.layer.shadowColor = Theme.darkShade?.cgColor
    menuBarCollectionView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
    menuBarCollectionView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    menuBarCollectionView.layer.shadowRadius = 4
}
```

That is my code for setting up the shadow for the colletionview1

Comment: In order to properly diagnose this a little better it would be awesome if you could provide some more code so I can run this in Xcode.

Comment: Either set the background color in the second collection view to clear or make sure the first collection view is above the second one. And next time please take the time to break up your question into sentences and use punctuation, it's pretty hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez sorry next time I will do a better job at asking question I have solved my problem thanks to Vishal sharma solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you said without 2nd collection view the shadow show up correctly then I think the problem is the constraint you provide to the 2nd collection view which 0 form all side. you can try 2 things

1: change the background color of 2nd collection view to clear

2: have some space between the 1st collection view bottom and 2nd collection view top.

Comment: Just fo reference for anyone in the future with this problem I tried Vishal's solution number 1 since I dont want to have spaces between my 2 collectionview. I just set all content background on my collectionview 2 and instead I set the background color for the UIView that holding all my screen elements.